# why the rails unable to import from include generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i try run the rails console the rails show me this error.

#### Steps to reproduce

```rb
bundle exec rails c

....

Traceback (most recent call last):
        12: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        11: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
        10: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
         9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
         7: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
         6: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         5: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
         4: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
         3: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
         2: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:13:in `<module:Rails>'
         1: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:17:in `<module:Generators>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:19:in `<class:Base>': uninitialized constant Rails::Generators::Actions (NameError)
Did you mean?  ActionPack
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version**:  Rails 7.0.4.2

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.7p221